# Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/szabbas/Sample-programs.git HEAD

Tags: git, bash, jenkins

[image]I am new to programming and trying to work with GIT repository and while configuring with the JENKINS is facing the error. I know it's a silly question but on a beginner point of view I am stuck and can't move forward. Please help me in resolving the error.

I have my code at the GIT repository and trying to build using jenkins. But it is giving the error as :
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/szabbas/Sample-programs.git HEAD

I have done to get the cloning through the GID bash and it is cloning with no issues with the URl. I am also attching[image] the image with the same.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Got here much later because of the error mentioned in the question and for new comers, now you should verify your git path at:

> Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > Git

In my case it didn't have the path to git binary in the `PATH` environment variable, so I added: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to it.

Answer (score 19):

I got the answer...just wanted to post here so that if some new programmer are there (like me) can look the basic things :-

```
While going in the project--> Configure--> set the path of the git correctly.
```

It should be till the bin and then append git.exe like 
*\bin\git.exe

Comment: Hey Syed I am too facing the same error, but couldn't understand where to change or what modification need to be done. Do I need to modify the Repository URL in the Jenkins or Environment variable in the System? For anything can you show with an example? Could you please explain in detail

Answer (score 13):

In my case this issue happened because of there is no **git** installed on my CentOS server.

1. sudo yum install git
2. git --version

After installing git i just make sure that my Global Tool Configuration default pointed to git
Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > Git

- Name : Default
- Path to Git executable : git

just posting this may help you in case of similar issue you had

Comment: super, helped me

Comment: On red hat 7 I had to change the path to the result of running: which git

Answer (score 4):

Please give the installation path of git.exe in Git executable field in the Global Tool Configuration.In my case it worked after the path was set as below
[image]