# Clone git repository in Jenkins is not working

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to connect bitbucket Git repository in Jenkins.
I created repository and added two files.

I can see two choices, 
HTTPS
SSH

In my system, I am able to clone my repository by below command,

> git clone
>   https://keval1234patel@bitbucket.org/keval1234patel/repo1.git

The problem is, When I give same url in Jenkins, it shows below error,

[image: Jenkin error]

One more thing I noticed is, In my bitbucket, I don't see clone option as I can see in other articles,
I see like below,

[image: HTTPS url]

When I try to brows URL, it shows me 404 error, **But same URL is working for clone repository in local system,**
I unchecked "This is a private repository" checkbox as well.
[image: 404]

Where do I need to change to integrate my git repository with Jenkins?

Comment: Is it a private repository

Comment: No, In settings I unchecked "This is a private repository" checkbox.

Comment: I can access you repository with the link `https://bitbucket.org/keval1234patel/repo1.git` so I'm not totally sure why you have a dead link
What appends if you use this link in your jenkins ?

Comment: The URL for browsing code in bitbucket will be different than for cloning.  Check the projects/repos available first.

Comment: Ok, may be it was browser issue for giving 404 error, But still Jenkins showing same error in other browsers as well.

Comment: Got from this link, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863528/failed-to-connect-to-repository-error-performing-command-git-exe-ls-remote-h"

Answer (score 0):

Those, who may have same issue, Need to set git.exe path in Jenkins configuration.

```
While going in the project--> Configure--> set the path of the git correctly.
It should be till the bin and then append git.exe like *\bin\git.exe
```

In my case, it is

**C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe**