# Jenkins intergration with github

Tags: github, jenkins

I am not able to integrate the jenkins with Github, seeing the following error:

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe
>   ls-remote -h https://github.com/Ram2923/TestAutomationEStore.git HEAD

See the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you try to connect to git from the Jenkins slave manually to verify connectivity?

Comment: @Ram : I believe this([failed-to-connect-to-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863528/failed-to-connect-to-repository-error-performing-command-git-exe-ls-remote-h)) post will help you out