# got error: Failed to connect to repository, while adding git project to jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

tried to connect my jenkins that installed on VM and also git is installed overthere (if it has any connection to these error), and i got these error while try to add the gitHub link,
the two errors are because i did also try with the configuration of SSH but it looks that there is no related thing to my problem with the SSH thing

[with SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1gcK.jpg)

[without SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhY4e.jpg)

update: i saw that there is these [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863528/failed-to-connect-to-repository-error-performing-command-git-exe-ls-remote-h) on my problem, so my questions are:

1. i understand that i need the git installed on my pc, is it right?
2. i need to add the full path to the git with the git.exe like : C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe ?

   3. what is the usage of SSH if so?

Comment: you should install git inside VM and config git in `Jenkins -> manage jenkins`. Another thing if your host pc access internet through proxy, you need to config proxy  `Jenkins -> manage jenkins`

Comment: @yong Thanks, about 2. do i need the full PATH to exe file?
and what is the SSH for?
my pc is not behind proxy so i'm alrgiht with that