# Unable to connect my git repository to Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, devops

I'm trying to connect my git repository to Jenkins server but while adding the repository, I'm getting the following error.

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/XYZ10/Jenkins_Test.git HEAD
```

A [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLVwv.png) is provided here.

Comment: The authentication method seems to be missing. Add a credential in `Manage Jenkins` inside `Manage Credentials` once that is done it will be available for selection in the dropdown in your screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/szabbas/Sample-programs.git HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863528/failed-to-connect-to-repository-error-performing-command-git-exe-ls-remote-h)

Answer (score 0):

Just add your credentials to jenkins, as mdabdullah mentioned. And choose it in your job's config and be happy)