# Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git.exe ls-remote -h

Tags: jenkins, devops, jobs

While trying to add my repo in the SCM section in Jenkins I am getting the below error. Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git.exe ls-remote -h

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/szabbas/Sample-programs.git HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863528/failed-to-connect-to-repository-error-performing-command-git-exe-ls-remote-h)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are using bad credentials. Make sure the user you are putting in the configuration part has at least read permissions in the remote repository.