# Jenkins not connecting to GitLab

Tags: git, jenkins, plugins, gitlab, connection

when we add the Repository URL in Jenkins job the error is given below.

Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command:

```
git ls-remote -h
```

Please tell me do we need to install git manually on the jenkins server or it will be taken care by installing the jenkins git plugin?

because jenkins git plugin is installed already, but I have not installed git manually.

Please note credentials are okay.

jenkins need to clone my repository from GitLab, while running the job.

Comment: First, Can you see your gitlab form jenkins master? For example ping your gitlab?

Comment: Someone else had already a similar problem, you can read answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863528/failed-to-connect-to-repository-error-performing-command-git-exe-ls-remote-h